# About installing rasterframes module in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I successfully installed pyrasterframes with pip in cmd, but when I try to import it in jupyter notebook I get the following error: "No module named 'pyrasterframes'". Could you help me please?

Comment: Did you restart the jupyter server after installing?

Answer (score 0):

This issue solved by removing your specific environment from jupyter by the following instruction:
"jupyter kernelspec uninstall envname"
and then installing ipykernel and readding the environment to jupyter notebooks as following:
"conda install -c anaconda ipykernel"
"ipython kernel install --user --name=envname"
notice that I should open jupyter notebooks after activating my env in cmd.
I think you can use this solution to solve similar installation problems with any other modules.